# Use htaccess to rewrite folder.domain.com to www.domain.com/folder

Tags: .htaccess, dns, url-rewriting

I want to set up a blog on my current domain at

http://www.ashrobbins.com/folder/

and use htaccess so that it can be reached by simply going to

http://folder.ashrobbins.com

The rewrite I currently have in my .htaccess is below.

RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L,NC]

But I get a page not found when I go to folder.ashrobbins.com in my browser...

Answer (score 0):

You must setup ashrobbins.com in your host to serve content from a local folder, and add a 'folder' folder inside it.

And also setup folder.ashrobbins.com in your host to serve content from another local folder. As I can see, you haven't setup folder.ashrobbins.com nd therefore you receive that error.

It seems you are creating a new site and doesn't know how to do it. If it's new, just setup subdomain.ashrobbins.com and put your site on it. If there's nothing already served in ashrobbins.com/folder/ just don't mess with it.